# How to move a subdirectory with its contents to another directory with NSIS

Tags: nsis

this is the first time I work with NSIS, I want to edit an script NSIS to allow me:

If first instalation -> create the directory "Affaires" in the location "C:\Users\ali.ait-mouhoub.ext\AppData".

If it is an update (So the directory "Affaires" it already exists in "C:\N.O.E") -> move the directory "Affaires" with its contents to "C:\Users\ali.ait-mouhoub.ext\AppData".

The current script creates the directory "Affaires" in "C:\N.O.E".

Can you please help me modify my script to meet my needs?

Comment: In the future, please don't post the full code, unless required to reproduce the problem. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is preferred here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the both the new and old locations are on the same volume then you can use `Rename`:

```
Section
Rename "$InstDir\Stuff" "$InstDir\OldStuff"
SectionEnd
```

If the new location might be on a different volume then you have to copy+delete:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
ClearErrors
CopyFiles /Silent "$InstDir\Stuff" "x:\Backup"
${If} ${Errors} 
  MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Unable to move!"
${Else}
  RMDir /R "$InstDir\Stuff"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I want to edit an script NSIS to allow me:

If first instalation -> create the directory "Affaires" in the location "C:\Users\ali.ait-mouhoub.ext\AppData".

 If it is an update (So the directory "Affaires" it already exists in "C:\N.O.E") -> move the directory "Affaires"  with its contents to "C:\Users\ali.ait-mouhoub.ext\AppData".
The current script creates the directory "Affaires" in "C:\N.O.E".

Can you please help me modify my script to meet my needs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the code you provided me it works very well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to do with NSIS to detect each user's session and move the Business directory (for example C: \ Users \ xxxxxxx \ AppData \ Roaming \ N.O.E \ Business).